# How can I get more ancient arrows?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've finished the Divine Beast quests and heaps of side quests, but I've never received any more than a handful of ancient arrows. How can I buy or farm more?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ancient Arrows can be obtained from:

- [In 9 treasure chests in Hyrule Castle](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Arrow) - three have 1 arrow, five have 3 arrows, and one has 5 arrows.
- At [Akkala Ancient Tech Lab](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_Arrow) for purchase after reactivating the blue flame furnace as per Eduardo Melzer's answer.

  - 1 arrow costs 90 Rupees, 2 Ancient Screws & 1 Ancient Shaft.
  - 3 arrows cost 250 Rupees, 6 Ancient Screws & 3 Ancient Shafts.
  - 5 arrows cost 400 Rupees, 5 Ancient Springs, 5 Ancient Shafts & 5 Arrows.

Comment: Note that buying the arrows in "bulk" (bundles of 3 or 5) will save you a little bit of rupees, though I believe the material cost (2 screws, 1 shaft, and 1 arrow per ancient arrow) is the same no matter which bundle you buy.

Comment: I've added the additional costs for 3 and 5 arrows. The material cost does change with 5 arrows, using springs instead of screws.

Comment: Also, if you give enough beetles to... ...Beedle, then from time to time when greeting you it will give you an Ancient Arrow (at least in master mode, can't remember if he does in normal mode). But this is not a very convenient way to get them.

Comment: I heard that using Ancient Arrow on a Guardian yields more parts than the arrow costs at AATL.

Answer (score 12):

You can buy ancient arrows at the [Akkala Ancient Tech Lab](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Akkala_Ancient_Tech_Lab), after reactivating the furnace with blue flame